# How to achieve a stacked/overlapping recyclerview list similar to chrome's tab list

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I'm looking to reproduce something like the chrome tabs list, so the viewholders will overlap as a stack if you scroll to the top and fan out as you scroll down. This is quite common in Android so I was wondering if there was a simple/ready-made solution.

Thanks!

[image: Chrome tab list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/loopeer/CardStackView library to achieve your functionality.